# System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator over System.Collections.IEnumerator advantages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am very much confused in this question.

> Which of the following advantages does
>   System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator provide over
>   System.Collections.IEnumerator?
>
> a: It adds properties for direct access to both the Key and the
>   Value
>  b: It is optimized to handle the structure of a
>   Dictionary.
>  c: It provides properties to determine if the
>   Dictionary is enumerated in Key or Value order
>  d: It provides
>   reverse lookup methods to distinguish a Key from a specific Value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a: yes

b: Enumerator doesnt handle collections it just enumerates them

c: Dictionary is not sorted (internally they are but not on the key)

d: absolutely not

The important point is that its used for non-generic dictionaries.